# Self-improvement tag needs rescoping?

Tags: discussion

Self-improvement tag says "Questions about improving yourself as a person, working on flaws in your personality and helping improve your interpersonal skills."

That said, a question which is about self-improvement -- as opposed to "interpersonal-improvement" will quickly get closed as off-topic.

Example:  [How to stop doing bad habits?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/how-to-stop-doing-bad-habits)

I know I'm pushing maple syrup uphill here, but we should at least edit the self-improvement tag so as to not give people false indication that such questions are welcome.

Update:  maybe change it to simply say, "Questions about helping improve your interpersonal skills."?

**Update:  From answers & comments, there appears to be support for retiring the tag...**

Answer (score 2):

I think the missing key here is self improvement generally vs self improvement with regards to a specific interpersonal problem. Which should seem kinda obvious given the name of the site and all...

Also, the specific question was horrifically broad regardless, so it should have been closed regardless.

---

Sorry shot from the hip there...

As far as rewording the tag description goes, it probably could be worded better, but it still seems pretty obvious in it's current wording.

But then again I suppose we can't count on people thinking these things through, so maybe a slight adjustment would be in order... Perhaps:

> Questions about improving yourself as a person, and  working on flaws in your personality, with the goal of improving your interpersonal skills.

Comment: Certainly question was too broad; I should not have answered it, but was in an unusual mood.  The issue is not that that question is off-topic, I won't fight that, but that our documentation is inconsistent.  And if we're going to be rigid on our rules, it's only fair that we don't offer tag descriptions which make people think that an "**intra**personal skills" question (ha!) would fit.

Comment: After update ... that 'adjustment' part is all I'm asking for here.

Comment: Actually I'm second guessing whether this is a useful tag at all... Only 8 questions, 4 of which are closed. @akaioi

Comment: "self-improvement" at least to me usually connotes individual, inward-focused efforts.  I think you could make a respectable argument to retire it.

Answer (score 1):

> Questions about improving yourself as a person, working on flaws in your personality and helping improve your interpersonal skills.

This sounds like a meta-tag, which means it should be deleted. It's also very broad.

Possibly there's an alternative meaning of self-improvement, but I can't think of one that would make for a really useful tag for this site.

Answer (score 1):

> The term “self-improvement” broadly refers to the act of improving yourself, but it can also be applied to a number of different topics. Self-improvement can include personal development in terms of leadership skills, goal setting, visualization skills, organizational skills, time management, and mind power.

That's what google says self-improvement is. Taking that, we can only edit the tag wiki to something like:

> Questions about improving your interpersonal skills.

Because questions about improving other topics are off-topic here and questions that are on-topic here should be about interpersonal skills I think the tag is superfluous and should be removed.

I think that if people ask questions here about their Interpersonal skills, it is sort of implied they are looking to improve themselves, that they are looking for personal development in terms of interpersonal skills.

Comment: Wouldn't this description make the tag kind of useless?

Comment: @apaul, that's my point... that this is  (very generally) the only description the tag can have, and that thus the entire tag is useless ;)